# pexpect not passing entire byte string

Tags: python-2.7, pexpect

I wrote a simple program  in C that receives a string in a buffer then prints out the buffer in hex and aborts() if it finds "\x04" in the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buf[16] = {0};
    int i;

    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02x ", buf[i]);
        if(buf[i] == 0x04)
            kill(getpid(), SIGABRT);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This works if I pass output from a program via a pipe, e.g.
    perl -e 'print "\x08\x08\x04\x08"' | ./fget-test

However I get the wrong output using pexpect:
    0x54 0xd0 0x08 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

It seems as though the 0x04 never makes it through?

Here's the python code I'm using for pexpect:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import pexpect
import sys
import os
import io

print "\x54\xd0\x04\x08\x0a\x0a"

c = pexpect.spawn('./fget-test')
c.setecho(False)
c.maxsize = 1

c.expect('Name:')
os.write(1, (b"\x54\xd0\x04\x08\x0a"))
os.write(c.fileno(), (b"\x54\xd0\x04\x08\x0a"))

print c.readline()
```

Why is the \0x04 never making it when using pexpect? I realize I can use subprocess.Popen but in this case I cannot as it's a small testcase for a larger program to help diagnose what's actually occurring. When piping the pexpect python program to xxd I can clearly see the "0x04" making it through.

Comment: you should use `c.sendline()` instead of `os.write(c.fileno())`

Comment: In this case, c.write(c.fileno(), ..) was used to test whether the behavior was specific to c.sendline() or if it didn't matter. os.write() was left in as it didn't matter which I used, the behavior was the same.

Comment: yes. It won't change the result (that is why I've posted it as a comment and not an answer). You should use `.sendline()` API provided by `pexpect` that is known to with other `pexpect` parts.

Answer (score 0):

Appear to have gotten this fixed. The solution was to import tty and then call tty.setraw on the file descriptor.

Comment: `b'\x08' == b'\b'` (backspace character). The explanation might be that `pexpect` allocates a terminal (pseudo-tty) and you can't pass arbibrary binary data via a terminal; [some characters are special](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09)